# Ao gerar uma sopa de letras com letras aleatórias como colocar as palavras sem coinciderem?

Tags: python

Penso que fui explicito. É dado num ficheiro .txt na primeira linha o tamanho da grelha e de seguida as palavras que devo colocar na sopa de letras geradas. 
O problema está que eu quando gero a sopa as palavras coincidem nas suas posições o que não é o pretendido. Alguém me pode ajudar?
A função que interessa é a por_palavra. Apenas coloquei o resto do codigo para entenderem melhor.
Aqui deixo o codigo:

```
import random
import string
fi=input('Insira o nome do ficheiro de entrada(entry.txt): ')
fo=input('Insira o nome do ficheiro de saida(.txt): ')
tamanho_grelha=[]
words=[]
matriz=[]

def ler_ficheiro(arquivo):
       file=open(arquivo)

       n=file.readline()
       lista=n.split()
       lista=list(map(int,lista))  #coloca o tamanho da sopa em uma lista
       for i in lista:
           tamanho_grelha.append(i)

       for line in file:
          line=line.replace("\n","") #coloca as palavras em uma lista
          words.append(line)
       file.close()


 def gerar_grelha():
       n=tamanho_grelha[0]
       p=tamanho_grelha[1]
       for i in range(n):
          matriz.append([])
          # EDIÇÂO: identei o loop abaixo - 
          # creio que havia uma erro de identação aqui
          # ao colar o programa no stackoverflow
          for j in range(p):
              matriz[i].append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)) #escolhe uma letras aleatorias para a  matriz

def por_palavra(palavra,grelha,w):
      n=tamanho_grelha[0]
      p=tamanho_grelha[1]
      palavra = random.choice([palavra,palavra[::-1]]) #escolher se a palavra será invertida ou não
                #horizontal,vertical,diagonal
      d = random.choice([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]) #decide o sentido da palavra

      xtamanho = n  if d[0] == 0 else n  - len(palavra)
      ytamanho = p if d[1] == 0 else p - len(palavra)

      x= random.randrange(0,xtamanho)
      y= random.randrange(0,ytamanho)  #posição

     for i in range(0,len(palavra)):

           grelha[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i]=palavra[i]
           return grelha
def escreve_ficheiro(in_file,out_file):
   leitura=open(in_file)
   escrita=open(out_file,'w')
   ler_ficheiro(in_file)
   gerar_grelha()
   escrita.write(str(len(words)) + "\n")
   for i in words:
       escrita.write(i + "\n")
   for palavra in words:
       grelha=por_palavra(palavra,matriz)
    l="\n".join(map(lambda row:"".join(row),grelha))
   escrita.write(l)

    leitura.close()
    escrita.close()


escreve_ficheiro(fi,fo) #chama a função
```

Por exemplo, esta saída:

```
             spepvawio  
             ofclrmhhh  
             cclvlaijl  
             rirosrtne  
             finaiegom  
             whrzzldur  
             fyceaonee  
             ywuygelbv  
             clsalilyg
```

Comment: Nota: sopa de letras (pt_PT) = [caça-palavras](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%A7a-palavras) (pt_BR)

Comment: (Você fez bem em colocar o restante do código - nao seria possível responder a pergunta vendo só a questão `por_palavra` - mesmo por que não seria possível entender como a grelha tinha sido criada.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já percebeu, somente com a informação constante na grelha se ela já estiver preenchida, não é possível (ou muito difícil, mas possível) para a função "por_palavra" perceber se está sobre-escrevendo alguma palavra já colocada. Um outro problema na função "por_palavra" é que se a palavra não couber na posição e sentido escolhidos, ela não tem como abortar e tentar sortear outra posição.

A ideia que tive resolve os dois problemas ao mesmo tempo: passe a grelha criada, mas "vazia" (isso é, com espaços ou um marcador no lugar das letras randômicas) enquanto estiver colocando as palavras - desta forma, no caso da palavra ficar por cima de outra letra é só reiniciar o processo de "por_palavra" para a mesma palavra. Depois das palavras colocadas, basta preencher o restante da grelha, trocando só as posições vazias por letras aleatórias -

re-escrevi as funçoes necessárias - voc:ê va precisar de pequenas adaptações no seu programa para usa-las - mas basicamente é chamar a função "criar_grelha" antes de várias chamadas a "por_palavra" e por fim a função "preenche_grelha". Sua função "gera_grelha" deixa de existir.

```
def cria_grelha(tamanho_grelha):
    # Python tem desdobramento de sequências no assignment
    # essa única linha atribui os valores para n e p
    n, p = tamanho_grelha
    matriz = [ [" " for j in range(p)]  for i in range(n) ]  
    return matriz


def por_palavra_interno(tamanho_grelha, palavra,grelha):
      n, p = tamanho_grelha
      palavra = random.choice([palavra,palavra[::-1]]) #escolher se a palavra será invertida ou não
                #horizontal,vertical,diagonal
      d = random.choice([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]) #decide o sentido da palavra

      xtamanho = n  if d[0] == 0 else n  - len(palavra)
      ytamanho = p if d[1] == 0 else p - len(palavra)

      x= random.randrange(0,xtamanho)
      y= random.randrange(0,ytamanho)  #posição

      for i, letra in enumerate(palavra):
           char = grelha[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i]
           if char != " " and char != letra:
               # Se atingiu um espaço já preenchido - reiniciar o processo.
               # (A segunda condição permite que palavras que se 
               # cruzam com letras repetidas sejam criadas)
               return False
           grelha[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i] letra
       return True


def por_palavra(tamanho_grelha, palavra, grelha):
    contador = 0
    while not por_palavra_interno(tamanho_grelha, palavra, grelha):
        contador += 1
        if contador > 1000:
            raise ValueError("Não foi possível posicionar a palavra {}".format(palavra))


def preenche_grelha(tamanho_grelha, grelha):
    for i in range(tamanho_grelha[0]):
        for j in range(tamanho_grelha[1]):
            if grelha[i][j] == " ":
                grelha[i][j]= random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

(**nota**: Havia algumas identações erradas no seu código. O programa em Python sequer era válido como estava, e uma das identações gerava um erro de lógica. Eu corrigi algumas - mas percebi que restam outras. - Se você criou a grelha, deve ter o programa com a identação correta aí. Tome MUITO cuidado com identação em Python - se seu editor esta a embaralhar a indentação, troque de editor. Se estiver no Windows tente o sublimetext ou notepad++ - Não tente programar em Python sem um editor com suporte adequado a identação

)

Comment: Antes de mais muito obrigado por ter respondido. O problema é que está me a gerar um erro "ValueError: Não foi possível posicionar a palavra branco". Será que consegue saber do que se trata?

Comment: O código foi feito para gerar esse erro de propósito se não tiver como encaixar a palavra após 1000 tentativas.

Será que há espaço no diagrama para coner essa palavra? Um diagrama com 5 x 5 letras, em que essa fosse a terceira palavra ja pode ser um caso em que o erro ocorreria quase sempre.

Comment: Eu estou a fazer uma matriz 9x9 com 9 palavras. Será que é por isso?

Answer (score -1):

Opa amigo, eu não sei se entendi direito a tua dúvida, mas pelo o que entendi, tu tá querendo ler um arquivo e a partir dele gerar um conjunto de palavras aleatórias e adiciona-las em uma matriz sem que haja repetição de palavras adicionadas nas linhas. Se for isto mesmo, você pode criar a palavra como uma lista e então fazer uma verificação se o valor já existe na matriz antes de alocar, exemplo:

```
palavra = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if not valor in matriz:
    lista.append(valor)
```

Agora para fazer desta maneira, tu teria que alterar ou adequar algumas coisas no teu código, tipo como está adicionando os valores na tua matriz:

```
grelha[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i]=palavra[i]
```

Não sei se é viável para ti ou se essa ideia faz sentido para o seu problema, mas espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a dúvida. Nem o programa do O.P.